# Returning result from jquery ajax request to a variable rather than firing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experimenting with MCV using jquery. I'm making a call to an api, which returns data - what I want to do is return the data to a variable rather than call an additioanl function within my model. The following code doesn't do what I wish though **(the_data = result)**. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
function lookForSomething()
{
    var the_data = $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
                            url: TheUrl, 
                            dataType: "jsonp", 
                            success: function(result) { return result; } 
                            });
    return the_data;
}
```

Many thanks,
J

Comment: are you hitting a server or are you actually using a jsonp invocation?

Comment: I am using this to query the google books api and I was getting an error when not using jsonp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand you correctly, you want the data returned by TheUrl to be the return value of the lookForSomething.

Technically, you *could* do this, with the async option:

```
function lookForSomething()
{
    var the_data;
    $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
                            url: TheUrl, 
                            dataType: "jsonp", 
                            async : false,
                            success: function(result) { the_data = result; } 
                            });
    return the_data;
}
```

I strongly urge you **not** to do this.  It's un-Javascript-like and it will lock up the user's browser while it's running.  Much better to pass in a callback to the function and invoke it from `success`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm happy to learn a more javascript-like approach to MVC but it's proving tricky. Essentially I want the controller to request data from this function and then send that data to a "view" function which writes the returned data to the browser. Adding invoking a function from success makes the "model" behave more like a controller...

Comment: If the controller passes a callback in to the model, and that callback (which is part of the controller, albeit one invoked by the model) sends the data to the view, would that arrangement satisfy your aesthetic of how MVC should function?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function lookForSomething()
{
    var the_data;
    $.when(
        $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
                            url: TheUrl, 
                            dataType: "jsonp", 
                            success: function(result) { the_data=result; } 
                            });
    ).done(function() {
        return the_data;
    }).fail(function() {
        return '';
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that this is still asynchronous, so when you make a call for `var ddd = lookForSomething();`, ddd will not have the value you expect since the call may still be running.  The only reason I brought up `$.when()` is because it seems like you require a lot of dependencies. `$.when()` allows you to wait for [multiple ajax commands](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when).

Comment: Thanks for this - the when() method is new to me - I'll check it out.

Comment: +1 for bringing up the excellent `$.when` function.  -1 for implying that it would solve the OP's problem.  The returns in the callbacks go nowhere.

Comment: @Malvolio: Yeah, I think you're right.  That function is still pretty useless; it should probably have a callbackfunction as a parameter.